# Return value of Glympse sendTicket method

Tags: return, glympse

What does the return value of the sendTicket method indicate? Sending was successful? Unfortunately it is not documented.

```
virtual bool Glympse::IGlympse::sendTicket  (const GTicket &ticket)  [pure virtual]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Glympse::IGlympse::sendTicket()` presents Send Glympse wizard. The method also performs some validation (checks input arguments and platform state). `false` is returned if any of those checks fail. The value of `true` indicates that Send Wizard is successfully presented.

Comment: Thank you Egor for your response! This really helped out.